# How to prevent user from sending default value for a GUID (or any non-nullable types)?

Tags: entity-framework

Let say I have this entity

```
public class Course
{
   public Guid OrganizationId { get; set; }
}
```

This won't work because Guid is a **non-nullable** type. It will produce the default value **00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000**.

```
builder.Property(x => x.OrganizationId )
       .IsRequired();
```

How to check that the value being sent won't be the default value.

Thanks for helping

Comment: *Users* have to provide a guid, really?

Comment: yes.  Applications calling this api are getting that somewhere else